# AppEngine SSL fail from command-line

Tags: linux, google-app-engine, ubuntu, ssl, openssl

I loaded a RapidSSL/GeoTrust certificate into my AppEngine application. The website loads into the browser with SSL perfectly.

However, when I verify the certificate from the command-line (Ubuntu 13.04), it fails. It's a general SSL failure, so all of my Python requests fail, too ("urllib3" fails, which incites "requests" to fail):

```
$ openssl s_client -connect www.XYZ.com:443 
CONNECTED(00000003)
3073689800:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:177:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 225 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
---
```

I use the certificate for one of its ASs on another server running NGINX, and there are no problems verifying that, at all:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect XYZ.com:443 
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 C = US, O = "GeoTrust, Inc.", CN = RapidSSL CA
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/serialNumber=gQpQo/GwZhs9/JqYi8P8DsQNFmVC5VQB/OU=GT09052054/OU=See www.rapidssl.com/resources/cps (c)13/OU=Domain Control Validated - RapidSSL(R)/CN=www.XYZ.com
   i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust, Inc./CN=RapidSSL CA
 1 s:/C=US/O=GeoTrust, Inc./CN=RapidSSL CA
   i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFRjCCBC6gAwIBAgIDDOW3MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAMDwxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVT
<truncated>
S6YumLnJrUVoCA==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/serialNumber=gQpQo/GwZhs9/JqYi8P8DsQNFmVC5VQB/OU=GT09052054/OU=See www.rapidssl.com/resources/cps (c)13/OU=Domain Control Validated - RapidSSL(R)/CN=www.XYZ.com
issuer=/C=US/O=GeoTrust, Inc./CN=RapidSSL CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 3023 bytes and written 375 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.1
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: A69E838824AF4F74228A82105A74D708A63CB5FDE042A04072A937A9A25DC1C7
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 35EACC6FCFA5F901AA355C0379289EE33FEB77334A95EC45A4A9D7CD22E4C944C76F998C2D9AAAF635FD88D02CDB7B08
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 300 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 5f 78 c7 0c da f1 7b ee-52 7a 4d 36 c0 28 b0 d7   _x....{.RzM6.(..
    <truncated>
    0090 - 5e fc 2c 37 d4 6f 20 0b-a6 aa 62 f4 df 90 1e 18   ^.,7.o ...b.....

    Start Time: 1374291906
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
    ---
```

The site isn't complete yet, so I can't share the domain.

I'd appreciate any insights.

Dustin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using SNI or VIP?  If you're using SNI, you'll need to use -servername with openssl.

Comment: Ahahaha. I love you, man (SNI). Why don't I have to do that for my NGINX server? How do I do that from code (Python 'requests', specifically)?

Comment: Your NGINX server probably doesn't need to use SNI because it only knows about a single certificate, so it doesn't need to "think" about which cert to serve up.  SNI is only necessary when you're trying to serve multiple domains and multiple certificates off of the same IP address.  tes

Comment: Regarding Python, SNI isn't supported by the standard SSL package in Python 2.x. Some libraries may have added it themselves though.  Also, the URLFetch Service on App Engine supports SNI.

Comment: To elaborate on this, "urllib3" added SNI support, but this only works if Python is [allegedly] equal or greater-than version 3.2 (allegedly.. see https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/commit/52be1ff4e808a5fee284d6538cbf37b145968094#urllib3/util.py). Specifically, it tries to import ssl.SSLContext . Else, the support isn't there to attach the server-name to the SSL context: context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname). Once I migrated my client to Python3, everything suddenly worked.